# crontabでPHPを実行したいが、mysqlに接続できない

Tags: php, cron

現在cronについて勉強しており、自己解決が難しく感じたため質問させてください。

## 問題

テストでMySQLからデータを取得し、テキストログに書き出そうとしたところ、`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`というエラーが出てうまくいかない状況です。

## 開発環境

- macOS
- MAMP 5.5
- PHP Version 7.3.8
- MySQL 5.7.26

```
htdocs/
└──cron_test/
    └──index.php // cronから実行するファイル
```

## これまでの経過

まず、いきなりデータベースを操作せずに、現在の日付をログ出力するようにしました。

**crontab**

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cron_test/index.php > /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cron_test/cron.log 2>&1
```

`which php`をして返ってきたPHPのパスを記述してます。
実行するphpファイルは、htdocs内のcron_testディレクトリの中です。

**index.php**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$date = new DateTime();
$datetime = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

error_log("$datetime\n", 3, dirname(__FILE__) . "/debug.log");
```

**結果**

```
2020-05-29 11:35:00
2020-05-29 11:36:00
2020-05-29 11:37:00
2020-05-29 11:38:00
```

結果は、1分ごとにPHPが実行されているのが確認できました。
続いて、crontabの設定はそのままで、Mysqlからテストデータを取得し、ログファイルの定期出力を試みました。

ソースコードは下記です。
　
**index.php**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$date = new DateTime();
$datetime = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost;charset=utf8mb4',
      'root',
      'root',
      [
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
      ]
  );
  $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM users');
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8', true, 500);
    exit($e->getMessage());

  }
  foreach($rows as $val) {
    $user_id = $val['user_id'];
    $send_id = $val['send_id'];
    $name = $val['name'];
    $email = $val['email'];
    $comment = $val['comment'];
    $status = $val['status'];
    $created_at = $val['created_at'].'...';

    error_log("$user_id.$send_id.$name.$email.$comment.$status.$created_at.$datetime.\n", 3, dirname(__FILE__) . "/debug.log");
  }
```

**cron.log**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

cronのログファイルに上記エラーが出力され正常に読み込めない状態となりました。

なお、**cronを使用せず、PHPファイルを実行（ブラウザリロード）すると、正常に動作します。**

### 確認したこと

- mysqlソケットの確認
  [CakePHPでMySQLに接続しようとしたら「SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory」と出た - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Yorinton/items/bfdf962fe4b7339866f6)

こちらの記事をみて、php.iniの設定も確認してみたのですが、

接続先が`/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`となっており、MAMPのmysqlソケットが設定されていました。

- hostを127.0.0.1に変更
  localhostを指定していたので、試しに127.0.0.1に変更してみました。

すると、`No such file or directory`のエラーがなくなりましたが、また違うメッセージが表示されました。

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

[PHPでMYSQLに接続しようとしましたがエラーが出ました - Yahoo!知恵袋](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11174448256)

この記事を見たのですが、MAMPのrootユーザーの設定は操作していないですし、
cronを使わずにPHPを実行すると接続できているので、何故なのかわかりませんでした。

- cronでPHPファイルの実行はできているが、mysqlにアクセスしようとするとエラーになる
- localhostであればディレクトリーがないと怒られる
- 127.0.0.1であれば、rootでアクセスできないと怒られる

MAMPを使っていることが原因かもと思ったりしているのですが、根本的な解決に至っておりません。
解決方法など、わかる方おられましたら、ご教授いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: cronはどのユーザで登録していますか？cronで起動する場合、ユーザログイン時の環境変数が引き継がれなかったと思います。必要な環境変数が設定されていないため、今回の現象が発生すると推測します。必要な環境変数を設定した後にphpを起動するスクリプトを作成し、cronに登録してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: phpのパスを`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.x.x/bin/php`に書き換えたら実行されました！ご回答いただきありがとうございますm(_ _)m

Comment: ともあれ解決してよかったです、自己回答も推奨されていますので、回答として投稿してはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

PHP のパスを `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.x.x/bin/php` に書き換えたら実行されました。

---

*この投稿は [@keisuke1223 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/67116/crontab%e3%81%a7php%e3%82%92%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e3%81%8c-mysql%e3%81%ab%e6%8e%a5%e7%b6%9a%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment73654_67116) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*